# finding the value in the series object and displaying in the tooltip of the high chart using angular 4

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am already displaying the x and y values on my tooltip of the highchart in my angular 4 application. Please see the formatter function of the tooltip. The graphdata array is initialised with three values as you can see below
 If you in the spine chart code, i am passing series object to static chart method. I now have access to the series object. The series object contain array 
 of data objects. Each element contains values for e.g.  { 90000, 1, 1000000}. How do I find the third value based on the first two values. I think i would need 
 find if point.x == firstelement and point.y == second element then show third element.
 So syntax wise i was thinking series.find()  but not sure how to construct it

I am trying to populate the third row with the label Captive Required in the table construct of formatter function. Full code available below under the title spline chart component

```
const table = function(format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        txt += row('GRAPH_XAXIS', format(point.x));
                        txt += row('GRAPH_YAXIS', format(numberPercentPipe.transform(point.y)) + '%');
                        txt += row('Captive Required',  + '%');
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };
```

This is how the chartseries gets initialised

```
  this.chartSeries = value.map(element => ({ data: element.graphData, name: element.strategyName, color: element.strategyColor }));
```

Graph data

```
trigger2Output.StressTestAnalysis.GraphData = new decimal[][]
            {
               new decimal[] { 90000, 1, 1000000},
               new decimal[] { 91000, 1, 2000000},
               new decimal[] { 92000, 1, 3000000},
               new decimal[] { 93000, 1, 4000000},
               new decimal[] { 94000, 1, 5000000},
               new decimal[] { 95000, 1, 6000000},
               new decimal[] { 96000, 1, 7000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434,1000000},
               new decimal[] { 121, 3434, 1000000}
            } ;
```

Spline chart component

```
    import { Component, Input, OnChanges, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe, NumberPercentPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';


@Component({
    selector: 'splinechart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
    chart {
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
         padding:0;
      }`]
})

spline chart component

export class SplineChartComponent implements OnChanges {
    static chart(shortNumberFormatPipe: ShortNumberFormatPipe, numberPercentPipe: NumberPercentPipe, translate: TranslateService, graphLegendTitle: string, series: any) {
        return {
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                margin: 25,
                itemMarginTop: 0,
                symbolRadius: 0,
                symbolHeight: 20,
                symbolWidth: 20,
                useHTML: true,
                title: {
                    text: graphLegendTitle,
                    margin: 50,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic',
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            },
            exporting: {
                chartOptions: {
                    scale: 1,
                    legend: {
                        allowHTML: true,
                        enabled: true,
                        margin: 25,
                        itemMarginTop: 0,
                        symbolRadius: 0,
                        symbolHeight: 20,
                        symbolWidth: 20,
                        useHTML: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    },
                    chart: {
                        width: 1500,
                        height: 600,
                        events: null
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_XAXIS')
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_YAXIS')
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return numberPercentPipe.transform(this.value);
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,

                formatter: function() {
                    let isMillionNumber: boolean = false;
                    const row = function(label, value) {
                        const key = 'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.';

                        return '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">' + translate.instant(key + label) + ': </td>'
                            + '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + value + '</b></td></tr>';
                    };

                    const transformNumber = function(value) {
                        isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(value);
                        if (isMillionNumber)
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);
                        else
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 0);
                    };

                    const table = function(format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        txt += row('GRAPH_XAXIS', format(point.x));
                        txt += row('GRAPH_YAXIS', format(numberPercentPipe.transform(point.y)) + '%');
                        txt += row('Captive Required',  + '%');
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };

                    let point = this.points[this.points.length - 1].point;
                    return table(transformNumber, point);

                    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                        return millionNumber >= 1000000;
                    }

                },

            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    events: {

                        legendItemClick: function() {
                            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
                            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
                            }
                            this.chart.redraw();
                        }
                    },

                    allowPointSelect: true,
                },
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle'

                    },
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    showInLegend: false
                }]
        };
    }

    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public height: number = 400;
    @Input() public yaxisdata: any;
    @Input() public selectedRating: string = '';
    @Input() usedInPdf: boolean = false;

    private shortNumberFormatPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();
    private numberPercentPipe = new NumberPercentPipe(this._locale);

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let graphLegendTitle: string = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE');
        if (this.usedInPdf) {
            graphLegendTitle = '';
        }
        this.options = SplineChartComponent.chart(this.shortNumberFormatPipe, this.numberPercentPipe, this._translate, graphLegendTitle, this.series);
    }


    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }

    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        this._redrawLogic(data.series.currentValue);
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    public redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this._redrawLogic(this.series);
        this.chart.redraw();
    }

    private _redrawLogic(series: any) {
        let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }

        series.map(s => {
              this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });

        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is returning the whole object series.find(x=> x.data.find(x=> x[0] === 90000))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by using the following code

```
 let xyz= series
              .find(s => s.name == point.series.name).data
              .find(x => x[0] === point.x && x[1] === point.y);
```